# Tensorflow AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'manip'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I try to roll a tensor and in the Tensorflow documentation i found a function called tf.manip.roll() but when i use it i get the error message:

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'manip'

Has someone an idea where this function has moved?

Comment: Use this official conversion scripts from tensorflow. In your case, it may be `tf.roll()` instead of `tf.manip.roll`. https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/upgrade